# Building an advanced form in iOS

Tags: ios, forms

I have a master/detail setup in XCode 4, which is essentially a multipart form with the essential items in the master view, and other items that can be added as needed.

What I want to do is have each item (objects in an NSMutableArray) present a view (in the detail view) with several form elements such as text fields and pickers, when it is selected in the master view.

What is the best way to have each item on the list display its appropriate form elements in the right hand view, as doing it all in the storyboard seems undoable?